# no shadows where mesh intersect, weird glow instead,

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows, ambient-occlusion

Hey I am getting these weird glow instead of shadows near the edges or where the mesh intersects, I am rendering in Eevee and have AO turned on.
[image: The example]

Answer (score 0):

In Light settings, low Bias setting of shadow. If it does not help, try set up contact shadows:

[image]